# inputting a file line by line into a structure

Tags: c++

I am having problems in putting lines of a file into a structure. It is inputting the same line over and over again. Here is the function

```
bool readInventory(string filename)
{
int answer= false;
ifstream openfile;

openfile.open(filename);

if(!openfile.eof())
{
    products *pProducts;
    pProducts = new products[21];


    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {

        openfile >> pProducts[i].PLU;
        openfile >> pProducts[i].name;
        openfile >> pProducts[i].opption;
        openfile >> pProducts[i].price;
        openfile >> pProducts[i].amount;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        cout << pProducts->PLU<<endl;
        cout << pProducts->name<<endl;
        cout << pProducts->opption<<endl;
        cout << pProducts->price<<endl;
        cout << pProducts->amount<<endl;
    }

    answer=true;

    openfile.close();
}
return(answer);


4101 BRAEBURN_REG 1 0.99 101.5

4021 DELICIOUS_GDN_REG 1 0.89 94.2

4020 DELICIOUS_GLDN_LG 1 1.09 84.2

4015 DELICIOUS_RED_REG 1 1.19 75.3

4016 DELICIOUS_RED_LG 1 1.29 45.6
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing the same Product over and over.  Index the Products in the second for loop like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    cout << pProducts[i].PLU<<endl;
    cout << pProducts[i].name<<endl;
    cout << pProducts[i].opption<<endl;
    cout << pProducts[i].price<<endl;
    cout << pProducts[i].amount<<endl;
}
```

Also, don't forget to `delete[]` your `pProducts` pointer!  You currently have a memory leak.  (You should really use a `std::vector` for this)